# Play asking for implicit application on Akka code even though it's imported

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

Using play 2.4.x. My code looks like this:

```
import play.api.Play.current

val linkedinParse = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[LinkedinParse], name = "linkedinParse")
```

Play produces the compiler error:

```
You do not have an implicit Application in scope. If you want to bring the 
current running Application into context, just add import play.api.Play.current
```

Even though i have that import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible reasons for this. The most likely is you have something else called current in scope... Try desugaring by explicitly passing the implicit parameter (you can always do this and this can be a great way to debug implicit resolution problems):

```
Akka.system(current).actorOf(...)
```

If that doesn't compile, then implicit resolution won't work for the same reason.